# Remote MySQL host thinks I'm on a different host

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote host, dev, from my webserver.  When I do this command from the webserve `composer.domain.com`:  `mysql -u username -ppassword -h dev.domain.com`, I get an error after authenticating that says access denied for username@sports.domain.com.

`sports.domain.com` *IS* a valid vhost on the webserver, but it's one of 14, and it's not the primary host, nor the one the IP resolves to via DNS.

Any idea where I should look to figure out why MySQL thinks I'm coming from `sports.domain.com` instead of the expected `composer.domain.com`?

Comment: IPs can only be reverse-mapped to a single hostname. If you're on a multi-domain host, you'll only ever show up as being "from" the one host that's listed in the PTR record. And that's the host mysql will use to determine where you're coming from.

Comment: We're using IP-based vhosts, not name-based.  So each domain has its own, unique IP.

Comment: but do you have control over which of those IPs is the egress point for your mysql connection?

Comment: Yes?  We built the box, so we can control everything.  I'm not sure how to check or set the egress IP for MySQL.

Comment: it's not mysql that's the problem - it's how the box's TCP stack decides to send out the connection from your client. It's THAT ip you need to control, and I don't believe PHP's mysql drivers let you choose a particular IP to bind to.

Comment: I'm getting this problem even when I use the mysql client from the command line.  But, it does make sense that the server configuration is the problem.  Any idea where I'd go to check that?

Answer (score 0):

During creating the mysql user, it should be specified the host where the user is allowed to connect. By default it is localhost. Try to add other user account on the database server try the following:

1. CREATE USER 'username'@'%'
   IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';

OR

1. CREATE USER 'username'@'sports.domain.com'
   IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';

% - it means that all clients are allowed to connect using user account.

Comment: The database I'm connecting to only contains public data, so this is what I've done to get around the problem.  It doesn't really solve the problem though.